# Too nervous to upgrade CiviCRM from 4.1.1

Tags: upgrade

I currently have CiviCRM 4.1.1 running on Drupal 7.16 at Siteground. When I try to make mirror versions (sandbox), things fail due to PHP versions on the host, conflicts, etc. I was told to upgrade the existing module within the CMS and upgrade the CMS in their locations, but I don't want to waste time when problems arise.

Could someone point me to the right person/group that could upgrade these for me to the latest of each that are currently stable?

I've asked some individuals for help, but can't seem to get confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach: start a completely fresh instance of D7 latest + 4.7 latest - and if that works well on your hosting -> then export your Contacts and Contributions and Event data, etc from your old instance into your new one; That gives you a nice chance to do some spring cleaning on your CRM data;

Comment: That sounds like you would lose a lot of old data such as Activities, Bulk Mailings, Relationships, Groups, Tags etc etc

Comment: That may just be what you want! We often purge activities tables (have seen one so big the admin could no longer civimail); smart groups often have to be recreated anyways post upgrade; recreating some right now that as we speak for a 4.6 -> 4.7 upgrade

Comment: PS of course you can also export Tags, Groups and import those into your freshe new D7/4.7

Comment: Thanks Karin. I'll speak with others who use the db and see if such a break makes sense - it might. Regardless, I'll verify that versions of Drupal 7 with civiCRM 4.7 will work on our host.

Answer (score 5):

if you are asking for professional support to undertake these upgrades and fix any issues that might arise as a result then you may want to contact some providers listed at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors.

When we (FUzion) are approached to undertake these types of support tasks then we would require suitable access (preferably SSH), would probably prefer to set up a dev version of the system to test the upgrade, while recognising that the server environment won't be equivalent.

Other information to have to hand would be PHP version the server is running etc.

Comment: I agree with Pete's answer. However, if you want to take on the endeavor, you should create a duplicate of your existing site and implement the upgrades via your test site.  This should give you an idea of how much work you may have to take on and if you are suited to perform the upgrade yourself.

Comment: Thanks Pete and themak for your insights. Regardless of the method I decide to take, I have upgraded in the past and I remember the chore to get everything working again. Making a sandbox db in another location makes sense and so I will try that this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to have a fresh install as KarinG suggested. There truly needs to be some cleaning of data and this will make that activity possible without too much trouble.

Also, I've verified that the Siteground server will support the latest versions of Drupal and CiviCRM - so, here I go.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions!

Comment: Buena suerte, señor.